# Change lineskip to fill the available space

Tags: line-spacing

Is there a way to change `lineskip` such that the text fills up a certain space?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight]{\linewidth}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Where the first line is at the top of the page, and the last line is at the bottom, as if there were a `\vfill` after every line.

Ideally, any solution would be fairly robust and allow a `wrapfigure` like

Not so minimal working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight]{\linewidth}
\blindtext
  \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{2in}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{picture.png}
  \end{wrapfigure}
  \blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use the `[s]` (stretch) option for the `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pass,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}[c][\textheight][s]{\linewidth}
\baselineskip=1\baselineskip plus 1fill % stretch as much as needed
\lineskip=0pt plus 1fill % just for safety

\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The `geometry package is used just to show the frame.

[image]

Comment: +1 Hmm I wonder who implemented that `s` option:(

Comment: Where do we get details of all such mysterious options?

Comment: @HarishKumar The LaTeX manual or "The LaTeX Companion", for instance.

Comment: Thank you. I need some more GiB of memory inside my brain `;-)`

Comment: This answer is really nice! I was really hoping to include a `wrapfig` in my minipage, but `wrapfig` overcalculates the space needed (as if it calculates the number of lines needed before the `\baselineskip` changes and then expands with the new `\basselineskip`). Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: @NathanaelFarley Difficult to say without seeing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Updated my question to reflect more of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Fixed! If I add `\baselineskip=20pt plus 1pt minus 1pt` just before the `wrapfigure` and then reinstate `\baselineskip=1\baselineskip plus 1fill` at the beginning of the next paragraph, `wrapfigure` behaves correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Ooh good question (+1) learn something new every day.

Normally you could set `\baselineskip` to a stretch space and it would stretch to fill the space, but it is defeated by the boxing and unboxing that `minipage` does behind the scenes.

Possibly the simplest thing is to use a primitive `\vbox` and shrinkable glue.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}


\noindent\vbox to \textheight{\baselineskip=\textheight minus \textheight
\blindtext
}
\end{document}
```

[image]